FetchableFluentQuery in spring data jpa not selecing specific entity fields dynamically
I want to select specific fields from a sql table. I am using FluentQuery.FetchableFluentQuery in a spring data jpa project. Here is my sample code:
@Entity(name = "user")
data class User(
    @Id
    var id: String? = null,
    var userName: String? = null,
    @Embedded
    var name: NameEntity? = null,
    @field:JsonProperty("displayName")
    var displayName: String? = null,
)

interface UserRepository :
    JpaRepository<User, String>,
    JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {
    @EntityGraph(value = "User.groups", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)
    fun findWithGroupsById(id: String): User
}

class UserDao(
    private val userRepository: UserRepository,
) {
    private fun getUsers(
        spec: Specification<User>,
        pageRequest: PageRequest,
        fields: Set<String>,
    ): List<User> {
        val result =
            userRepository.findBy(spec) { query: FluentQuery.FetchableFluentQuery<User> ->
                query.project(fields).page(pageRequest)
            }

        return result.content

    }

When I call the function
getUsers(spec, listOf("userName", "displayName")),

I expect the underlying select statement to be like this:
select userName, displayName from user

instead of this the underlying select query specify all the columns from the table!
I expect FetchableFluentQuery to select only specified columns from the table. May I know what's going wrong there.

Finally, I could fix the issue by using createTupleQuery():
    val criteriaBuilder = entityManager.criteriaBuilder
    val criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery()
    val root = criteriaQuery.from(User::class.java)

    val predicate = spec.toPredicate(root, criteriaBuilder.createQuery(), criteriaBuilder)
    criteriaQuery.where(predicate)

    val selections = listOf("userName", "displayName").map{
        root.get(it)
    }
    criteriaQuery.multiselect(*selections.toTypedArray())

    val query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)
    val resultList = query.resultList

